# How can I place the text in this box like this with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a div box that have css like this:

```
.productinfo2 
{
margin-top: 20px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
height: 60px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
width:800px;
float:right;
margin-right:5px;

}
```

And this is how it looks right now in HTML:

```
         <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)" alt="" />
         <div class="productinfo2">
         <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h2>
         <p id="price">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)</p>
         <input type="text" class="Quantity">
         <p id="total">699</p>
         </div>
```

I want to make the text and textbox to be exacly like this img but I cant seem to get it like that:

[image]

My problem is to get everything in one line, like the img.

Any kind of help is appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/TUT7G/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off.  The only things you really need to think about here is that both h2 and p have inherit line breaks you need to get rid of.

h2 you can get rid of it easily using display:inline.

For P, I would just recommend using a span instead.

More specifically using your code as the example you can do this:

```
<html>
<style>
.productinfo2 
{
margin-top: 20px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
height: 60px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
width:800px;
float:right;
margin-right:5px;

}

.productinfo2 h2 
{
font-family:Georgia;
font-size:18px;
color:#BED600;
display:inline;
}

#price
{
font-family: Verdana;
font-size:12px;
color:#333333;
margin-left:40%;
}

#price input
{
  width:10px;            
}    

#total
{
font-family: Verdana;
font-size:12px;
color:#333333;
margin-right:20px;
float:right;
}

</style>
<body>


         <div class="productinfo2">
         <h2>test</h2>
         <span id="price">price <input type="text" class="Quantity"></span>
         <span id="total">total: 699</span>
         </div>

         </body></html>
```

Check it out on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/muKty/

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect place for a table. Tables are (very) bad for page layout for a whole host of reasons (some of the most important being how they make life difficult for those who use screen readers to "see" web pages). However, in your case your data appears to clearly be in tabular format--that is to say that it makes logical sense to put it in a table.

However if I am mistaken, then you can use inline block elements. Inline block elements combine properties of block elements (such as allowing for a width) and inline elements (such as not taking up an entire line in its containing element). Here is a quick example:

```
<div>
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 10em;">text</span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 10em;">more text</span>
    <span>even more text!</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 10em;">another line of text</span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 10em;">more text on the next line</span>
    <span>even more text on the next line!</span>
</div>
```

And here it is as a fiddle if you don't believe that it works ;).

http://jsfiddle.net/wLZwb/

Comment: I am using inline-block now as you told me but how do I create space between the <h2> and the <p>. It looks like this now Title 699 but I want more space between Title and 699

Comment: If both elements have display: inline-block then you simply need to modify the width. Increasing the width of the element will push everything to its right over. If this isn't working, then be careful that your CSS isn't overriding itself somewhere. The Firebug extension for Firefox can help you out with that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TUT7G/3/ - Is that not what you are looking for??? (You can adjust the columns as you wish so long as the widths add up.)